# How to set Textbox value on click command

Tags: c#, uwp, resourcedictionary

On my Resources.xaml(Resource Dictionary) I have a DataTemplate :

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ProductDetailsContentTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
        <Viewbox Margin="27,0,28,0" Height="200" >
            <Image UWPUtil:ImageExtensions.CachedUriSource="{Binding ImageUri}" />
        </Viewbox>
        <TextBlock Text="Description" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="24"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ProductDescription}" Style="{StaticResource SubtitleTextBlockStyle}" FontSize="30"/>

        <TextBlock Text="Barcode" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="24"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Barcode}" Style="{StaticResource SubtitleTextBlockStyle}" FontSize="30"/>

        <TextBlock Text="Weight" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="24"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Weight}" Style="{StaticResource SubtitleTextBlockStyle}" FontSize="30"/>

        <TextBlock Text="Quantity" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="24"/>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="25*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="25*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button x:Name="SubtractQytyButton" Grid.Column="0" Content="-" FontSize="24" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        Margin="5,0" Style="{StaticResource TestButtonStyle}" FontWeight="ExtraBold"
                        Click="SubQytyButton_Click"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="QuantityTextBox" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" FontSize="24" Margin="5,0"
                         KeyDown="Quantity_Keydown" TextChanging="Quantity_TextChanging"
                         Text="{Binding Quantity, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource DecmialConverter}}" MaxLength="5" TextAlignment="Center"/>
            <Button  x:Name="AddQytyButton" Grid.Column="2" Content="+" FontSize="24" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                         Margin="5,0" Style="{StaticResource TestButtonStyle}" FontWeight="ExtraBold"
                         Click="AddQytyButton_Click"/>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate><br>
```

I file nested it using the File Nesting from Mads Kristensen , here is the thread: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.FileNesting

so I have a Resources.xaml.cs on my ResourceDictionary
my problem is I want to set my QuantityTextBox Value on AddQytyButton and SubQytyButton click command, here is my click command event:

```
private void AddQytyButton_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //does not exist in the current context
        QuantityTextBox.Text = "test";
    }
```

OR

```
private void AddQytyButton_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = sender as Button;
        // this is not working as null reference
        var textbox = (btn.Parent as StackPanel).Children[1] as TextBox;
    }
```

Thanks,
NicoTing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should cast `btn.Parent` to a `Grid` instead of a `StackPanel` since you are using the former in your XAML.

```
var textbox = (btn.Parent as Grid).Children[1] as TextBox;
```

Comment: Am I able to use

    var textbox = (btn.Parent as StackPanel).Children[1] as TextBox;
on that? please provide a code
Thanks

Comment: Try use MVVM and set it.

Comment: I dont think its a good method for if you change the code order that you cant get Description